# Initilize var by if - else

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, .net-4.0

I have a method which sorts a list < T >  which gets a bool parameter which indicates if to sort by `ascending` or by `descending`.

I would like to use `var` as returned type.

```
protected void SortlistBy(bool IsByDescending)
    {
        var result;  
        // Initialize the var according to parameter value  
        if (IsByDescending == false)
            result  =  listModelElements.OrderBy(x => sort(x)).ToList();
        else
            result  =  listModelElements.OrderByDescending(x => sort(x)).ToList();
    }
```

I get the following error:  `Implicitly-typed local variables must be initialized`.
Any ideas?

Comment: Can't do this !!! Read [var (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383973.aspx). And are you doing something with `result`? I can only see assignment !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Ternary operator like:

```
var result = IsByDescending ? 
               listModelElements.OrderByDescending(x => sort(x)).ToList() :
               listModelElements.OrderBy(x => sort(x)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. You have to declare a type.

`var` is **not** a keyword for late-binding.

Answer (score 1):

You simply can't - the type of a variable has to be either explicitly declared or be *inferrable* at the point of declaration. And, since the variable isn't being assigned anything, its type can't be inferred by the compiler.

Just declare `result` as a `IEnumerable<T>` or `IList<T>`.